# Node js - app.get method with query params - internal server error

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

**Controller.js**

```
  function _loadMoreItems() {
                    console.log("load more items");                
                    var paginate = {
                        page : $scope.page,
                        perPage : $scope.perPage
                    };
                  ItemService.loadItems(paginate).then(function(result){
                        console.log("pagination done");
                        console.log("result");
                        console.log(result);
                        console.log("result length");
                        console.log(result.length);
                        for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
                            $scope.itemList.push(result[i]);
                        }
                        $scope.page = $scope.page + 1;
                    },function(err){
                        console.log("error");
                        console.log(err);
                    });
                }
```

**Service.js** - ItemService

```
angular.module("myapp.item")
    .factory("myapp.item.service", ['Restangular',
        function(Restangular) {
            var restAngular = Restangular.withConfig(function(Configurer) {
                Configurer.setBaseUrl('/api/item');
            });
            return {
                create: restAngular.all('')
                    .post,
                loadItems: function(paginate) {
                    return restAngular.all('query').getList(paginate);
                }
            }
        }
    ]); 

   Here I pass the paginate object as query param.
```

**The below is my route in node js.**

```
ApiRouter.get('/query',auth.requiresLogin, ApiCtrl.load);
```

**The below is my node js method to handle the get.**

```
exports.load = function(req, res) {
    console.log("req query");
    console.log(req.query);
    var myList=[];
     return res.status(200)
                .send(myList);
};
```

I get the below error.

```
http://localhost:3000/api/item/query?page=0&perPage=3  500 (Internal Server Error)
```

**Error trace**

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "query" at path "_id"
    at ObjectId.cast (D:\Branching\8OctItemPagination\myapp.io\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\ob
jectid.js:116:13)
    at ObjectId.castForQuery (D:\Branching\8OctItemPagination\myapp.io\node_modules\mongoose\lib\s
chema\objectid.js:165:17)
    at Query.cast (D:\Branching\8OctItemPagination\myapp.io\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:233
6:32)
    at Query.findOne (D:\Branching\8OctItemPagination\myapp.io\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:
1118:10)
    at Query.exec (D:\Branching\8OctItemPagination\myapp.io\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mqu
ery\lib\mquery.js:2213:16)
    at Query.exec (D:\Branching\8OctItemPagination\myapp.io\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:179
7:19)
    at exports.itemid (D:\Branching\8OctItemPagination\myapp.io\app\item\server\controllers\api\item-api.js:36:10)
    at paramCallback (D:\Branching\8OctItemPagination\myapp.io\node_modules\express\lib\router\ind
ex.js:385:7)
    at param (D:\Branching\8OctItemPagination\myapp.io\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:36
5:5)
    at Function.proto.process_params (D:\Branching\8OctItemPagination\myapp.io\node_modules\expres
s\lib\router\index.js:391:3)
info: GET /api/item/query?page=0&perPage=3 500 24.740 ms - 0
```

I am getting Internal server error for no reason. If I change the 'getList' in my router to 'post(paginate)' then I dont get this error. Some where I am missing out to write for getList. Please let me know where I am wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's matching on another controller action.  The url `/api/item/query` is matching on one of your routes that is doing an ID-based query.  I'm assuming it's something like a `'/item/:id'` or the like.

The handler for that route is trying to use that route param to query Mongo, probably using a `findById` or similar and passing the id which at this point has the value 'query'.

Comment: ya ..u are right.. it is also erroring out at one line that is for /item/:id method. Now how can I rewrite the route?

Comment: It should match the first one in the stack, so just put the /api/item/query one before the /api/item/:id one.  That said, it's not a great API to have multiple meanings for the same path.  I'd probably rethink your endpoints to avoid that.

Comment: even then.. if i want to run /api/item/:id then..that may run /api/item/query by mistake right? So now I made /api/item/all/query.. Its working fine.Thanks for your help!

Comment: Cool, yes, that's why I said that you shouldn't use the same route for two different things.  having /item/all/query doesn't really solve it either, but at this point we're in the "more art than science" realm of debating best URL patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Your code block is looking for an item in the database with the _id of "query". That doesnt sound right to me based on common sense.

```
loadItems: function(paginate) {
                return restAngular.all('query').**getList(paginate)**;
            }
```